# Is there any way to have more than one character?

Tags: dayz-2012

I realize that in *DayZ*, your character persists through servers.

The problem is, I have two different groups of people with whom I would like to play. Group 1 is, for argument's sake, in position A, while Group 2 is in position B. I'd rather avoid having to trek across the zombie riddled countryside each time I was playing with a different group.

**Is there any way to have more than one character? Perhaps by strategic save-file movement?**

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no.  I know the server identifies you using a GUID unique to your ARMA II (or steam..?) account, and I've heard rumors of hackers being able to change this GUID to unban themselves, but I don't know of any non-bannable way to do it.  I doubt there is one.

Comment: it's bound to the arma2-key. not to GUIDs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is No. Your character is kept on a central remote server that is tied to the CD key of your game. So with out buying a separate game and installing both keys it is not possible to get two characters.

The other option that you will run into from time to time is when a server is not hooked up to the central repository in which case your character exists on that server and that server alone. This is generally against the server agreement with the developer of DayZ however so these are very rare and often mistakes in configuration.

Comment: *"the official answer.."* - source?

Comment: I would assume it'd be official due to the statement that your character is saved to your CD-key

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very easy way to get a second character.  But you have to buy an additional copy of ArmA2.  I didn't necessarily mean to find this out but a friend bought a copy of ArmA2 for day z, he didn't like it.  So before he uninstalled it, I went into the registry and got a copy of the ArmA2 CD key and exported it.  Then I went into my own registry and exported my ArmA2 CD key.  Both were saved as a .reg file.  I then emailed that file to myself and put it on my computer.  Now when I want to play using his character, I run the .reg file to install his CD key in my registry before starting ArmA2.

Answer (score -1):

Playing on different maps is the only non-bug, non-bannable, and easy way to do it without configuring your game. All you have to do is use DayZ Commander (which is a program used to run, update and install DayZ/ArmA II) and install the other maps available (this is done for free). Then you will have a separate character on each map.

Comment: This answers the title, but not the body of the question. -1